# How do you share a video with the JavaScript SDK?

Tags: video, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using FB.ui to allow users to share something to their wall. It works fine, but I was hoping I could share a video - like you can do with the Open Graph tags. Here is my current code:

```
$('#share').click(function() {
        FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'feed',
            name: 'App name',
            link: 'http://www.facebook.com/pages/mypage',
            picture: 'http://url.com/picture.jpg',
            caption: 'Type in a caption',
            description: 'A description of the share',
        });
    });
```

With the Open Graph tags you can do the following:

```
<meta property="og:video" content="https://url.com/video.swf" />
<meta property="og:video:height" content="259" />
<meta property="og:video:width" content="398" />
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://url.comimage.jpg"/>
```

When Facebook scrapes your page, they put the image in the shared post with a "play" button, then when you click it the SWF shows up.

Is this doable with the JS SDK?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is old, but here's the answer:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title> Publish </title>
</head>
<body>
      <div id='fb-root'></div>
      <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>

      <input type="button" value="Publish " onclick="publish(); return false;" />

<script type="text/javascript">
FB.init({appId: "APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

function publish()
{
      var feed = {
            method: 'feed',
            picture: 'THUMB',
            link: 'http://google.com',
            name: 'Google',
            description: 'DESCRIPTION',
            source: 'PATH_TO_SWF_OR_PLAYER_WITH_PARAMETERS',
            type: 'video',
      };

      function callback(response){
            if(response && response.post_id !== undefined) {
                  alert('published');
            }
      }

      FB.ui(feed, callback);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

More information [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/).

Comment: Definitely. I ended up figuring out there was a 'source' attribute that did everything for you. At the time they had 0 documentation for it which was extremely frustrating.